# Information in last two cells of UITableView is duplicate of first two

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which loads data from XML using the below code. It loads the information correctly, but the final two cells from the array are a repeat of the first two cells. I don't know if I'm loading it incorrectly; I `NSLog` out the values as I build the array and they are correct. I've also logged the final array and that's fine.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    ViewRoutesCell * aCell = (ViewRoutesCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ViewRoutesCell"];

    if (aCell == nil)
    {   
        NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewRoutesCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (NSObject *anObj in arr) {

                AssessObject *newObj1 = [[AssessObject alloc] init];
                newObj1=[totalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newObj1.routeImage]]];

                aCell = (ViewRoutesCell *)anObj;
                aCell.imgRoute.image = image;
                aCell.lblRouteText.text = newObj1.routeText;
                aCell.lblRouteImage.text = newObj1.routeImage;
        }
}
    return aCell;
}
```

It's loading to a custom cell. It seems to me that the problem may be related to the reuse of the cells. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must re-write your code as following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    ViewRoutesCell * aCell = (ViewRoutesCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ViewRoutesCell"];

    if (aCell == nil)
    {   
        NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewRoutesCell" owner:self options:nil];
        aCell = (ViewRoutesCell *)[arr objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    AssessObject *newObj1 = [[AssessObject alloc] init];
    newObj1=[totalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newObj1.routeImage]]];

    aCell.imgRoute.image = image;
    aCell.lblRouteText.text = newObj1.routeText;
    aCell.lblRouteImage.text = newObj1.routeImage;

    return aCell;
}
```

otherwise, you cells will be cached with old values.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the value to the cell if aCell != nil

if aCell != nil, it means that it find a reusable cells from previous created.

Therefore aCell keep what you created before and show you the repeat value

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are not very clear.

So lets step through it.

**Reuse**
When a table cell goes off the screen (e.g. is no longer visible) it goes into a pool of cells that are available for reuse these cells are tagged with a `reuseIdentifier` which may be like in your example `@"Cell"`.

**Why do we need a pool?**
`alloc`/`init`'ing objects is expensive and when scrolling a `UITableView` you could potentially be doing this a lot especially if the user scrolls fast. This will cause your `UITableView`'s scrolling to become slow and jerky.

**So how do I reuse?**
The method `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` main purpose in life is to give your `UITableView` a cell to display.

So the first thing you do in this method is call the method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. The `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method will check the pool of cells available for reuse and return `nil` if there are none or return a `UITableViewCell` for you to configure.

The following check:

```
 if (aCell == nil) {
```

is used to determine if we have a cell we can just configure or if we need to create a new one.

If `aCell` is `nil` then there was not a `UITableViewCell` available for reuse therefore we need to create one and give it it's initial config. This is a great time to set things like colours and other properties that only need to be set **once**.

After this `if` block we know we have a `UITableViewCell` that we just need to configure so now you can go ahead and set any labels or properties that are different for every cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    ViewRoutesCell * aCell = (ViewRoutesCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ViewRoutesCell"];

    if (aCell == nil) {   
        // Create a new cell and do any one time config
    }

    // Configuration that is different for every cell

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you always explicitly set all aspects of the cell's content in your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIdexPath:` implementation. If you fail to do that, any views in the cell that you fail to set will continue to have whatever content they acquired in their previous use.